# How to I apply a custom cell class to a CellTable using GWT 2.5?

Tags: gwt, cell, celltable

If I define a custom cell extending AbstractCell how to I use my custom cell in a CellTable?

My custom cell is composed of two Labels and an Image and is populated by a Contact object that holds the values for the labels and image.

How do I define a Column that references my custom cell to add to my CellTable?
Snippets from the code:

The abstract cell widget:

```
public class ContactCell extends AbstractCell<String> { ... }
```

The data class:

```
public class Contact  {
    String first;
    String last;
    String photo_url;
}
```

The code building the CellTable:

```
CellTable<Contact> results = getView().getContactsTable();
Column<Contact, SOMECLASSHERE> col 
    = new Column<Contact, SOMECLASSHERE>(new SOMECLASSHERE()) {
        @Override
        public SOMECLASSHERE getValue(Contact object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return WHAT?;
        }
    };
}
```

Is this a correct approach? And if so, how to I use my abstract cell?

Answer (score 1):

UiBinder always is an implementation detail, be it for a widget or a cell. Users of the class only see a widget or cell.

For instance, could you tell from their API that [`NativeHorizontalScrollbar`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/NativeHorizontalScrollbar.html), [`NotificationMode`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/NotificationMole.html) or [`ValueBoxEditorDecorator`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/editor/ui/client/ValueBoxEditorDecorator.html) use UiBinder? Would it change anything if they were not?

Comment: Thanks; you're spot on. I'll rephrase my question.